# Should "the" and "a" agree in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Example:

> She lowered her pen to the blank page and wrote **the** first
>   verse—followed by **a** second one.

In this case, I used *the* first and then *a* at the end. Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfectly correct. Otherwise how would you say:

'I went to THE World Cup in Brazil in AN aeroplane'?

You would either have to say 'a World Cup', or 'the aeroplane', both of which would be nonsense.

Comment: I think you're right. So, writing, "...wrote **a** first verse—followed by a second one" sounds weird?

Comment: In fact, if we're talking in antecedent basis (and I sure hope we aren't, but still), it's virtually required to use both in the same sentence.